# Structuring MongoDB Database and Collections for reduced redundancy

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, mongodb

I am importing data from an excel sheet which has 701 rows/records, but there are columns which contains redundant information.....

In my case for example - there are only 6 unique products and 5 Unique Countries but they are repeated in those 701 rows. My task is to Export all that data to MongoDB.

How should I structure my Database, should I create 2 collections i.e products, countries which will contain all unique data and then store their reference for each document in collection where my excel data will be stored?

```
This is the Document structure for now
[
  {
    country: 'CountryName',
    segment: 'BusinessType',
    product: 'Some Product',
    discountBand: 'High',
    unitsSold: 2574,
    grossSales: 772200,
    profit: 12870,
    dateTimeInUTC: 1383244190000,
    dateTime: 2013-10-31T18:29:50.000Z
  }
]
```

Comment: You could create a unique index. Then duplicated are not imported. However, you will get error which you need to catch (and ignore if "E11000 duplicate key error collection")

Comment: Redundancy/duplication isn't necessarily a bad thing.  What sort of queries do you expect to make?  Your collection doesn't seem like it would be that big really.  Are there other collections that might be joined to the often repeated info?  It might simplify future queries to just keep the repeated data in each document.  Having to `"$lookup"` data for every query will slow the query.  There may be a space/speed trade-off to make.

Comment: So the size of collection i.e the number of documents will totally depend on the excel sheet that user uploads, for now, I am filtering unique countries, segment and products by iterating each row and storing them in their own collection, then adding their ID to the row and store it in DB in another collection. 

Yes, as you said, for current codebase, I need to perform aggregation with 3 `$lookup`, 3 `$unwind `  and 1 `$set` stage for getting data from those collections, then add more stages if I want to manipulate the data, so the query is slow, that is why I need better solutions.......

Comment: @rickhg12hs commenting, just to notify you

Comment: I would explore having just one collection and then evaluate which data model is better suited to the application.